# run linux executable in c# with params

Tags: c#, linux, parameters, executable

I need to run a linux file without an extension with runtime parameters in c#, I would want to know either if you can do that directly with some function or you need to write a runtime bash script in-code.

example:

run c:/app -port=(changing port variable in code)

Comment: Look in to `System.Diagnostics.Process` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start

Comment: and how exactly do you run the process?

Comment: Since you are on Linux, are you using .NET Core, Mono ? I guess it doesn't matter. I will write an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical way to start a terminal application with arguments, wait for it to finish, then output what it sent to stdout.

```
using(var p = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = "/bin/ls", // File to execute
    Arguments = "~/Documents", // arguments to use
    UseShellExecute = false, // use process creation semantics
    RedirectStandardOutput = true, // redirect standard output to this Process object
    CreateNoWindow = true, // if this is a terminal app, don't show it
    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden // if this is a terminal app, don't show it
})
{
    // Wait for the process to finish executing
    p.WaitForExit();
    // display what the process output
    Console.WriteLine(p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
}
```

Comment: So for my case I would use "/home/program" as the filename and "-port=777" as the arguments? Is that the right syntax?

Comment: @fesdfadfa -- yes, that's how you'd do it

Comment: I tried this and it just says  Native error= Cannot find the specified file. I made sure the file is actually there, im still confused about the extension-less file, maybe this isnt the right way to execute them?

my input  :  ApplicationName='/home/ubuntu/.steam/SteamApps/common/'Retail Royale Server'/LinuxServer/IkeaBR_Server/Binaries/Linux/IkeaBR_ServerServer', CommandLine='-log -queryport=27020 -port=7780', CurrentDirectory=''

Comment: btw running this file through terminal with ./IkeaBR_ServerServer works