# C# using Process in Linux. Problem with passing arguments

Tags: c#, linux, process, mono

My program should start a Linux program and pass arguments to it. For debugging I print FileName and Arguments to the console.

```
private static void StartRecording(string channelName)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Starting recording of the channel {channelName}");
        if (RecordingProcesses.ContainsKey(channelName)) return;
        Process recordingProcess = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                UseShellExecute = false, 
                FileName = RecorderPath,
                Arguments = $"--appId {AppId} --channel {channelName} --uid {RecordingUid} --channelProfile 0 " +
                            $"--appliteDir {AppliteDir} --channelKey {GetToken(channelName)}",
            }
        };
        recordingProcess.Exited += delegate { OnProcessExited(channelName); };
        Console.WriteLine($"Starting process. FileName = {recordingProcess.StartInfo.FileName}, Arguments = {recordingProcess.StartInfo.Arguments}");
        recordingProcess.Start();
        RecordingProcesses.Add(channelName, recordingProcess);
    }
```

That programs raises an error and says that I use wrong arguments. After that I close the program and try to launch that process manualy through the terminal by copy-pasting the FileName and then Arguments from the debug message to the terminal and the program runs ok. Why does that happen? How can I start the process from my program with the same result as when I start it from the terminal?

Comment: perhaps this could be useful to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63237496/run-linux-executable-in-c-sharp-with-params

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the reason. It was because one of the argments contained a tilde. When running the program from terminal it was replaced by "/root". And when I used Process, it didn't replace tilde.

Comment: The tilde in terminal is expanded to the user's home. `~` in terminal is the same as `$HOME`. When the process is not run by your user or the ~ is not expanded, it won't work.
I am glad to see you were able to help yourself.